# How to delegate folder permission in exchange offline server?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to delegate permissions to my tasks, contacts and calendar folder on exchange offline server to others so that they can fetch items from my folders using exchange web services client. So far I cannot find any solution other than `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` command in exchange powershell. Is there any way to do this from outlook or exchange admin center?

I have looked into outlook and exchange admin center but could not find anything there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but in Outlook you can right-click on any folder, then left-click on 'Properties' and there you will see a Permissions tab. From there you can add folder level permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean Exchange OnPrem, if your trying to do it programmatically then EWS can be used to do delegate operations via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-add-and-remove-delegates-by-using-ews-in-exchange. EWS also has the ability to get and set permission at the Folder level like Add-MailboxFolderPermission eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-set-folder-permissions-for-another-user-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: I did found this but a client is requesting this feature and they want their IT/ops team to delegate folder level permissions through exchange offline server using outlook/exchange admin center.

Comment: You can use Impersonation in EWS to allow for that otherwise your only other option would be just to use Add-MailboxFolderPermission which you can use from managed code.

Comment: I just checked impersonation in EWS, but this also is configured using exchange management shell.

Comment: But you only need to do it once

Comment: Yes, but individually for each user and admin. Same was the case for folder delegation through exchange management shell.

Comment: I don't think you understand how Impersonation works, you create a Service account for your app, give that impersonation permission to that account and then it can then impersonate every Mailbox in your org (including any new mailboxes that are created). So it just a once off configuration that's need. Some org's don't like the use of impersonation because of the permission that are ultimately given to the Service Account. Otherwise your better sticking with PowerShell as that's the only thing that will give you RBAC/admin delegate model.